# openssl command hangs

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, digital-certificate

The following request to `openssl` hangs

```
openssl req -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need another argument, it expects to read a certificate from standard input.  Probably you meant to add `-new` as a command line argument, or you need to pass an existing certificate on standard in.

Answer (score 111):

I had the same issue when using `GitBash` in Windows 7, After hours of search this solved my issue:

```
winpty openssl genrsa -out ../private.pem -aes256 4096
```

Could give you some idea what is needed.

Comment: +1 and to note that my full command was different, but the key was placing "winpty" before the full openssl command.  I believe winpty adjusts standard input and/or adds mouse support which is required for some randomness that openssl uses to generate the key.  Otherwise it just hangs waiting for input which never comes (even if you type keystrokes or move the mouse).

Comment: this also helped me... how did you find that you need prefix command with winpty? what is winpty?

Comment: @Patlatus How did I find? = same as you = stackoverflow; don't know anything about winpty, tried to understand at the time but could not; so I said the heck with it, as long as it works.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1273181/why-do-i-need-prefix-openssl-with-winpty-on-windows-bash In case someone has the same question, basically because bash default is mintty which cant run openssl because of some conversions, so we use winpty for that

Comment: I was using this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516812/2567273) to create my own key and used this answer to git it working

Comment: using winpty helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux system, probably you simply miss to add "-new" to tell OpenSSL to generate a new certificate request